# Window and screen dimensions changing

Tags: javascript, browser, screen, zooming, screen-resolution

Is there a JavaScript event I can listen to if the window and screen dimensions change?  I know of the obvious `resize` event, but interestingly my window and screen dimensions are changing without this event being fired.

My setup is very peculiar-- I have two external monitors, one at a normal zoom level and the other at a 200% zoom level.  It seems as though in the process of loading the webpage, the window/screen dimensions (e.g. `window.innerWidth`, `window.innerHeight`, `screen.width`, etc etc...) are changing.

As a note, the browser I am using is IE11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to listen to dimension changes in a loop with setInterval

Something like this:

```js
"use strict";

let width = screen.width;
let height = screen.height;

function checkDimension(callback) {
    if (width !== screen.width || height !== screen.height) {
        console.log('Dimension was changed!');
    }
}

setInterval(checkDimension, 1000);
```

Comment: This is what I have in mind... but it's not an optimal solution.  The question remains, why are the screen dimensions changing at all?

Comment: can you provide me with more information about your case?